# Is there a Java local queue library I can use that keeps memory usage low by dumping to the hard drive?

Tags: java, queue, message-queue

This maybe not possible but I thought I might just give it a try.  I have some work that process some data, it makes 3 decisions with each data it proceses: keep, discard or modify/reprocess(because its unsure to keep/discard).  This generates a very large amount of data because the reprocess may break the data into many different parts.

My initial method was to send it to my executionservice that was processing the data but because the number of items to process was large I would run out of memory very quickly.  Then I decided to maybe offload the queue off to a messaging server(rabbitmq) which works fine but now I'm bound by network IO.  What I like about rabbitmq is it keeps messages in memory up to a certain level and then dumps old messages to the local drive so if I have 8 gigs of memory on my server I can still have a 100 gig message queue.

So my question is, is there any library that has a similar feature in Java? Something that I can use as a nonblocking queue that keeps only X items in queue(either by number of items or size) and writes the rest to the local drive.

note: Right now I'm only asking for this to be used on one server.  In the future I might add more servers but because each server is self-generating data I would try to take messages from one queue and push them to another if one server's queue is empty.  The library would not need to have network access but I would need to access the queue from another Java process.  I know this is a long shot but thought if anyone knew it would be SO.

Comment: I have never done it, but Apache ActiveMQ is another MQ server, which is open-source and written in Java. I believe it can be used as an embedded service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it id the approach you are looking for, but why not using a lightweight database like hsqldb and a persistence layer like hibernate? You can have your messages in memory, then commit to db to save on disk, and later query them, with a convenient SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as Cuevas wrote, HSQLDB could be a solution. If you use the "cached table" provided, you can specify the maximum amount of memory used, exceeding data will be sent to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filesystem.  It's old-school, yet so many engineers get bitten with libraries because they are lazy.  True that HSQLDB provides lots of value-add features, but in the context of being light weight....